# Google sheets custom function argument address for conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a custom function in Google Sheets with intention of using it for conditional formatting:

```
function f(cellValue) {
}
```

How can i get the address of the cell whose value i get in the *cellValue* argument?

The function should return true if the three cells above the given one are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do it directly.

But your function could take 2 more arguments:

```
function f(cellValue, rowNum, columnNum) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowNum, columnNum);
  var address = range.getA1Notation();
  return address + " = " + cellValue;
}
```

Example of the usage of the formula:

```
 = f(A1, row(A1), column(A1))
```

So we use native functions (`row` & `column`) inside custom formula.

---

OK, let's talk about your task.

The function should return true if the three cells above the given one are empty.

You may use this formula (no script needed):

```
=join("",OFFSET(B63,-3,,3))=""
```

Comment: I know a script is not necessary for this but still, it would be a lot nicer if i could encapsulate the logic in a named function. It might change in the future

Comment: I'm quite convinced now you just can't use your custom functions when doing conditional formatting in google docs

Comment: I've corrected the formula: `=join("",OFFSET(B63,-3,,3))=""`. It could be used for conditional formatting.